# how to write a join query with group by in eloquent laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables in my database.

user: stores users information.

book: stores each book information

book_reviews: stores review information (such as overall point) for each book by each user.

I want to write a query in Laravel to retrive books with highest average overall point given by users.

How do I write the following SQL query in Laravel using Eloquent?

```
SELECT books.*, AVG(book_reviews.overall_point) AS avg_point
FROM books JOIN
     book_reviews
     ON books.id = book_reviews.book_id
GROUP BY book.id
ORDER BY avg_point DESC
```

Comment: i assume the column `books.id` has a primary or unique key?  If thats not the case MySQL can't use [Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) to get valid data for all those other books columns

Comment: The 'id' column in the book table is the primary key. I ran the sql in phpMyAdmin and it works. i need to rewrite it in Laravel using eloquent.

Comment: "I ran the sql in phpMyAdmin and it works" yes that it works i know but if the data was correct that was the question.. "i need to rewrite it in Laravel using eloquent" why not using `DB::select( DB::raw("your_query'") )` and use your query directly ?

Comment: I can't use this solution because I need to use model's relations and functions. 
For example I have some appended attributes in Book model that I need to access.

Comment: @SiavashGolabi - Try `Books::hydrateRaw(<your query>)`. Or use Teoman's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve with `orderByRaw()` method. With this method you can order books with average overall point

```
Book::select("books.*")
    ->join("book_reviews br","br.book_id","=","books.id")
    ->orderByRaw("AVG(br.overall_point) desc")
    ->groupBy("books.id")
    ->take(10) # or how many book you want
    ->get();
```

Comment: I get this error after executing your query:

Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #19 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Comment: @SiavashGolabi I update my answeri can you try again ?

Comment: You can also add AVG to the select list: `Book::select("books.*", DB:raw("AVG(book_reviews.overall_point) AS avg_point"))`.